# I've been coding my website on Windows 7, just went on it on Windows 8, and it is messed up

Tags: html, css, layout

Okay, so for the past year or so, I've been working on my website on Windows 7. But now, I just checked it on my new Windows 8 computer, and the margins are all off. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've been working so hard on it, ditching my friends, playing 'hookie' to work on it, and now I just realized this, and its crushing me. Am I really screwed? 
I tried Google, found nothing. Hopefully one of you guys can help me out. Thanks.

> I've been teaching myself HTML/CSS, I haven't taken any classes for it yet, so I'm sort of new.

Most of my CSS is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb7u8L0q/1/#update)

Here is my relevant Javascript

```
var cacheTitle = document.title.replace("Flowtime.js | ", "");
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1228618-10']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Flowtime', 'Landing', document.title]);
        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();           
        Flowtime.showProgress(true);
        Flowtime.onNavigation(onNavigation);
        function onNavigation(e)
        {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Flowtime', 'Navigation', cacheTitle + ' > ' + document.title.replace("Flowtime.js | ", "")]);
        }
        Flowtime.start();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code / css with an example of what you are talking about.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Currently, i am on chrome on windows 8. My code is very long, and I have a few css and js files external. I'll put them in a fiddle.

Comment: Most of my CSS is in this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qb7u8L0q/1/#update

By the way, my website is
samtestphp.web44.net/servicesnewest.html

Comment: I'm a beginner; please don't judge my work and not help, I'm sorry if its a lot of code, I've been working on it for about a year.

Comment: Guys, I'm really starting to freak out. I lost 3 of my closest friends because I chose to work on my website over hanging out with them. A year of work,  I've tried google, I cant find ANYTHING. You guys are my only hope.

Comment: Please be patient.  People will respond.  There is a lot to look at and understand.  You won't be judged but you will get blunt, honest answers.  I am no expert either but one thing you should avoid is inline styling.  It makes it all much harder to follow.

Comment: Since this is a question related to CSS positioning, I think that the javascript for Flowtime / Google Analytics isn't relevant.

Comment: Also, you seem to be putting a lot of emphasis in both the question and the comments on how this is affecting you, but nearly no information about what you expect to see.  We can only see what you have now, but have no reference / mock up, or other information to know what it's *supposed* to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this is important to you. I myself, have been building a website for several years and it's not even public yet. But all I can do is offer my advice, I can't fix your website for you.

- When doing web development, it is the browser, not the operating system which you need to consider.
- It is essential that you consider what browsers your website will support.
- Once you have decided which browsers to support, you MUST test your site in these browsers and implement a design that will be uniform across them all.
- Do not use `!important` tags in your CSS unless ABSOLUTELY necessary.
- Code your site as simply as possible, for your own sake, and compatibilities sake.

I know it's stressful when problems come up after you've worked so hard and sacrificed so much, but it goes with the territory. Just calm down and everything will work out.